# Why does a malloc of 2GB or larger of memory in the Heap in C fail?

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, malloc

I want to allocate a specific size of memory on the C heap. As a test to do it I used the following piece of code (to check the maximum allowable value):

```
int main(void) {
   int *val;
   val=(int*)malloc(4096);
   if(!val)
      break;
   return 0;
}
```

The problem is that when trying a range of values with `malloc()`, at about a size of 1900MB it fails. Yet I have 16 GB of installed RAM with about 12GB free.

So I can't even think to allocate a higher value of memory.
Is there something that I'm doing wrong?
Is there something that I should know about `malloc()`?

I see many programs(like Virtual Machines)that use big amount of memory so i already ruled out the idea that is a security features of the OS.

Comment: Why do you want to allocate that much memory, though? Also are you using a 64-bit compiler or 32-bit?

Comment: `if(!val) break;` Who taught you that?? You don't even have a loop!

Comment: Well malloc() will give you the amount of memory you ask for (until you get a kernel panick or the OS refuses your request). Your question doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Can you show the code that actually fails?

Comment: @Adosi i’ve tried with a 32-but one, btw is just a test...

Comment: @hyde it doesn’t actually fail...it’s just stop at 1900mb (as the Task Manager said).

Comment: Just because Task Manager says the process has 1900MB of memory doesn't necessarily mean it can't get more.  That's just what it currently has mapped to that process.  As the process actually writes to that memory, the usage will increase.  Try using `calloc` instead which zeros out memory when it's allocated.

Comment: On 32-bit machines (with 4-byte pointers, or where you set `INTERNAL_SIZE_T` to 4-bytes on 64-bit machines), `malloc` is limited to `2^32` bytes. (more or less), see: [libc malloc source code](http://code.metager.de/source/xref/gnu/glibc/malloc/malloc.c)

Comment: this is really a windows question

Answer (score 0):

The pages allocated to your process is doesn't constitute the whole RAM. What do you think? The whole user program will not be allowed to access full RAM. The OS decided how much virtual memory your process will be allocated and then the program starts.  That is why you didn't show using the full RAM of your machine.

Long story short - your program is not given the whole RAM for use. If it did - then it would trigger a whole bigger problem than you think it is posing now. Also your idea of `malloc` use is not clear. When it is `NULL` which is returned by `malloc` it mostly calls for an error condition. Your code somehow abstracts those accept and introduce a redundant dummy `if` block which does nothing.

As a user program you will request memory - and in case it fails then it will return `NULL` and handle the condition accordingly.

Comment: @zDoes.: I am not sure how much you can mmanipulate. But this is hardly required.

Answer (score 0):

`malloc()` is a C and C++ run time function that is part of the Standard Library. The memory addressing capabilities depends on what compiler is being used as well as the build settings for that compiler.

I did the following test with Windows 7 x64 using Microsoft Visual 2013 with C++, when I am using the 32 bit build target settings (x86), then when I try to use `malloc()` to allocate a 4GB block of memory, `malloc()` returns a NULL pointer indicating the allocation failed.

This is expected because with Windows 32 bit OS, the maximum amount of RAM that can be addressed is a 32 bit pointer but in reality less than 4GB, somewhere around 3.5 GB of usable RAM I think due to way that Windows 32 manages physical memory.

Testing with two other sizes, 2GB (failed with a NULL pointer returned) and 1GB (succeeded with a valid pointer returned) indicates that the maximum that the 32 bit C++ run time allows is somewhere between 1GB and 2GB.

Then I changed the build settings from x86 to x64 to generate a 64 bit executable with 64 bit pointers.

With the change in build settings a call to `malloc()` with 4GB succeeded with a valid pointer returned.

Task Manager shows the following:
[image: screen shot of task manager showing memory usage]

See also [StackOverFlow How can I allocate all the availble memory in visual studio for my application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15606429/how-can-i-allocate-all-the-availble-memory-in-visual-studio-for-my-application)
 with the accepted answer that mentions the following:

> Getting a larger virtual memory address space requires a pretty
>   fundamental overhaul. Albeit that it is easy today, just target x64 as
>   the platform target. A 64-bit process has massive amounts of address
>   space available, limited only by the maximum size of the paging file.
>   You could limp along in 32-bit mode, as long as you can count on
>   actually running on a 64-bit operating system, by using the
>   /LARGEADDRESSAWARE linker option. Which increases the VM size from 2
>   GB to 4 GB on a 64-bit operating system.